# Laravel fails to execute multiple ssh commands?

Tags: laravel, ssh, laravel-4, phpseclib

I have to connect to ssh and execute two different commands one after another.

In Laraver docs i see that it's possible to pass array with commands to SSH::run() and of course i tried that.

But, for very interesting reason, it fails with a message "**Undefined offset: 1**".

Executing SSH::run() two times one after another, makes two connections, and that can be kin of an issue too.

Any idea what can be a problem?

It points me here as a point of fail:

**.../vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php**

**2988 $this->window_size_server_to_client[$channel]-= strlen($response);**

p.s. i also tried to connect commands in single line with && etc.. but again with a same error.

Comment: I think this is a PHP 5.6.1 error: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/491

Answer (score 0):

I didn't mention, i was connectiong to ssh server that is in windows powershell machine. So && (although mentioned somewhere in docs) and `n didn't work as newline, new command...

But ";" did.

I made it..

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this should work:

```
SSH::run($commands1, function($line1)
{
   SSH::run($commands2, function($line2)
   {
   });
});
```